# Handling Screen Densities & Sizes in iOS

Tags: ios, screen-size, screen-density

Android provides DP/DIP for handing different screen densities.

Is there anything similar in iOS or is it handled differently somehow?

For instance, if I set a UILabel height to 20, will it scale proportionally in iPhone4 and in iPhone7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we wont give fixed hight, If you provide fixed hieght for labels it wont change proportionally. Either you can provide layout (`autolayout`) relatively or  change height programatically for changing height according to the screen sizes.